# Unzip a .zip file to a specific folder using :zip module

Tags: path, erlang, directory, unzip

I'm trying to unzip a .zip file to a specific folder path:

http://erlang.org/doc/man/zip.html#unzip-1

```
:zip.unzip(zip_path, {cwd: "/tmp/test-extracted/"})

** (SyntaxError) test.exs:18: syntax error before: cwd
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:677: Code.require_file/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
:zip.unzip(String.to_charlist(zip_path), cwd: "/tmp/test-extracted/")
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several syntax errors here.

1) To call a function defined in a module, use `Module:Function(Arguments)`.

```erlang
zip:unzip(Zipfile).  % not zip.unzip()
```

2) Tokens begin with a lowercase character is called `atom`s, which are just some literals. You should use variables for the first argument of `unzip/2`.

```erlang
Zipfile = "/path/to/your/zipfile.zip".
zip:unzip(Zipfile).
```

3) For the second argument of `unzip/2`, let's see how to understand the document you post:

```
unzip(Archive, Options) -> RetValue
```

This is the function signature: two variable arguments and a return value

```
Archive = file:name() | binary()
```

The first argument should be of type `file:name()` or binary

```
Options = [Option]
```

`Options` argument should be a list.

```
Option = {file_list, FileList} |
    keep_old_files |
    verbose |
    memory |
    {file_filter, FileFilter} |
    {cwd, CWD}
```

There are several forms of the list, including the one you need: `{cwd, CWD}`, which is a tuple, whose first element is atom `cwd`.

We have all the knowledge to call `zip:unzip/2` correctly now:

```erlang
Zipfile = "/path/to/your/zipfile.zip".
MyCwd = "/path/to/working_dir/".
zip:unzip(ZipPath, [{cwd, MyCwd}]).
```

Comment: Your entire answer is wrong man, syntax errors almost everywhere.